# Flash type casting gone wrong

Tags: flash, type-conversion

Sorry, I'm new to flash I have this line of code:

```
            BaseEntry( _entryList[i] ).topTeamName = ((Team)(teamList.getNameAtIndex( i*2 ))).Name;
```

and I get the error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion
>   failed: cannot convert "[object Team]"
>   to ncaa.Data.Team.

What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is, instead of:

```
((Team)(teamList.getNameAtIndex( i*2 ))).Name
```

you want:

```
(teamList.getNameAtIndex( i*2 ) as Team).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

@walpolea is right... but for the sake of completeness you can also do it this way:

```
BaseEntry( _entryList[i] ).topTeamName = Team(teamList.getNameAtIndex(i*2)).Name;
```

which many argue is *faster* then using "as".